# Ruby Binary Search Issue - sorted array / x is nil error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know a few questions with a similar title have been closed for ambiguity, so I will try to be as detailed as possible.

I have a rails model called 'Badges' that have 13 badge objects that are predefined. Each badge object has a attr called 'condition', which specifies the number of points that a user must reach to achieve the badge.

My code for a method called 'reward_badge' is like this:

```
@user = User.find(self.user_id)

conditions = Array.new(13)
Badge.all.each do |b|
  conditions << b.condition
end

badge = Badge.find(conditions.bsearch_index{|x| @user.points >= x} + 1)
@user.badges << badge unless @user.badges.include? badge
```

So, I have a **sorted array** called 'conditions' which contains the point increments for each of the badges (ex. [1, 5, 10, 50...]). I want to get the badge that has a condition which is just smaller than the user's points, and award the badge if the user doesn't already have it.

And I decided that the 'binary search' that ruby provides is the best way to achieve this. But when I use the above code, I get errors saying that 'x is nil'. (more specifically, the error says that I cannot use the operator '>=' for a nil obj)

I am not sure how to resolve this, as I thought I followed what the ruby library specifies...

At the moment, I decided to temporarily use a case statement. I really hope to use this binary search method for a clearer solution. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Why dont you use `badge = Badge.where('condition <= ?', @user.points).order(:condition).last` ?

Comment: @Sajin Oh... right. I've been so desperate to use search algorithms that I completely forgot that there is the quick&easy 'where' method in ruby... wow I really need my head to be more flexible. So sorry I wasted your time with this basic question! Would you like to put that as an answer or should I just close the question? :)

Comment: @sajin Thanks for the great tip by the way!!

Comment: I'll add it as an answer

Comment: @Sajin Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fetch the badge based on user points, use:

```
badge = Badge.where('condition <= ?', @user.points).order(:condition).last
```